# python csv writing into two columns

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am trying to write the output of a python calculation to csv in two columns. I tried the following to achieve this, but failed.

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in [level, variable]:
        writer.writerow([row])
```

the print output of print(level, variable) is as follows,

```
(1, 0)
(2, 0)
---
---
---
(33, 8)
(34, 7)
(35, 6)
(1, 0)
(2, 0)
---
---
---
(33, 10)
(34, 1)
(35, 2)
```

How can I write this print output in to two columns of csv file?
Can anyone give a answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A csv is literally just a file with **C**omma **S**eperated **V**alues. So technically:

```
f = open("whatever.csv")
[for loop]
    f.write(f"{value1}, {value2}\n")
f.close()
```

should do the trick. Where value1 and value2 are the name of your 2 values.

Comment: I tried this but getting invalid syntax error in ` f.write(f"{value1}, {value2}\n") `. Is it due to I am using python2?

Comment: Yeah those are called format strings and where introduced in 3.6 I guess. But you could still use the old style of "%s, %s" % (value1, value2)  or %d instead of %s just google format strings python and maybe old-style.

Comment: sorry, I tried the old-style but could succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this .

```
  import csv
    
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(zip(level, variable))
```

you can also try

```
f=open(data.csv,'w')
for i,j in zip(level,variable):
    f.write(str(i)+","+str(j))
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. But this one writing only last line :(

Comment: Edited my Answer to have another method as well. If this is also printing the last values, you may need to look into your level and variable values.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but you should try to :

- Build a list
- Put in your list your tuples (python identifies tuples with parenthesis)
- Send your list of tuples in your csv

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
import csv

with open(df_path,'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['level_col', 'variable_col'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in range(list_len):
        writer.writerow({'level_col': level[i], 'variable_col': variable[i]})
```